# Geometric quality of orthophotos

Tags: orthophoto

I have a lot of historical orthophotos, like the year 1950 of a region

I have also of the same region the orthophotos of more recent years such as 2012

The question is how to compare and quantifying the geometric quality of both orthophotos?
For knowing what is the geometric quality of the historical orthophotos

Comment: Digitial Orthophotography and GIS can be a useful starter http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc95/to150/p124.html